# D3.js: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I use 3D.js library:

```
d3.select(`#myGraph`)
  .append('svg')

const svg = d3.select(`#myGraph svg`).append('g')

const nodeEnter = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag())

svg.selectAll(".node")
      .each(function (d: any) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("data-source", d.id)
      })
```

But I got the error:
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

How can I fix it without @ts-ignore ?

Comment: what is ```this``` referring to, please add more of your implementation?

Comment: this issue can occur if you're using the ```function``` key-word, which definitely has an implicit type to ```this```, but can be specified nonetheless...

Comment: @AshwynHorton I added the code

Comment: this solutions by Rodrigo should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the type annotation to the `this` in the function:

```js
  svg.selectAll(".node")
      .each(function (this: any, d: any) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("data-source", d.id)
      })
```

Or, if you don't want the explicit `any`, you can define it as `SVGGraphicsElement`, which is a general SVG element type. If you want to be more detailed it can be a more specific type (such as `SVGRectElement` or `SVGGElement`) to better describe the selection.

```js
  svg.selectAll(".node")
      .each(function (this: SVGGraphicsElement, d: any) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("data-source", d.id)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had an angular app where I needed to display information when I hovered over generated rectangles.

This was the problem:

```
boxes.on('mouseover', (mouseEvent, d) => { d3.select(this) ...
```

Same problem "this" implicitly type any ...

The event has current element called currentTarget
So instead of:

```
d3.select(this)
```

With my typescript app I have:

```
d3.select(mouseEvent.currentTarget)
```

This solved the problem for me.